# ¿Qué diferencia hay, en memoria, de las siguientes 2 sentencias?

Tags: java, string, manejo-de-memoria, objeto

```
String s1 = new String("Hola!");

String s2 = "Hola!";
```

Comment: Hola Arturo , has investigado algo? Has mirado como funciona el interprete de Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La diferencia consiste en el uso o no del *String pool*.

### Uso de la palabra clave `new`

Cuando creas un `String` usando `new`, se creará un nuevo objeto en el heap en tiempo de ejecución:

```
String s1 = new String("Hola!"); //Siempre se crea el objeto en el heap
```

### Uso de literales

Cuando creas un `String` usando un literal, el compilador busca en el *String pool* un `String` que tenga el mismo valor. Si lo hay, asigna su valor a tu variable. Si no lo hay, crea un `String` -**que es inmutable**- en el *String pool* y asigna su valor a tu variable:

```
String s2 = "Hola!" //No existe esta String en el pool, se crea
String s3 = "Hola!" //Ya existe. No se crea otra, se asigna su valor a s3.
```

### ¿Qué es el *String pool*?

El *String pool* es la forma que tiene Java de implementar la [Internalización de Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) (Traducido y resaltado por mi):

> En ciencias de la computación, la internalización de strings es una forma de **guardar sólo una copia de cada cadena distinta**. **Esta copia debe ser inmutable**

Esto significa que, en nuestro ejemplo, `s2`y `s3` apuntan al mismo objeto. Ésta es la razón por la que cosas como:

```
if (s2 == s3) {
    //cosas
{
```

Dan problemas. Esa comparación *podría dar* `true`, porque estás comparando exactamente el mismo objeto inmutable, pero siempre es mejor utilizar el método `equals()` para eso, porque no sabes cómo se crean:

```
String s1 = "Hola";
String s2 = "Hola";
String s3 = "Adios";
String s4 = new String("Hola");        

System.out.println(s1 == s2); //true
System.out.println(s1 == s3); //false
System.out.println(s1 == s4); //false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s4)); //true
```

Comment: Creo que tu último párrafo es incorrecto: No se recomienda comparar Strings así porque puede devolver true o no, dependiendo de cómo se han creado. Si fuese siempre true, no habría problema sería un comportamiento constante. Excelente respuesta, por lo demás

Comment: @PabloLozano cierto, editado.