# Por qué la clase String no tiene el método clone

Tags: java

Por qué la clase String no tiene el método clone, no se supone que hereda de Object y tendría que heredar este método?

Gracias.

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Por la misma razón por la que la hicieron **final** - para que no podamos modificarla una vez creada. Hay ciertas clases/objetos con son inmutables y String es una de ellas. Los diseñadores del lenguaje decidieron que no puedes clonar un objeto String porque si lo haces vas a tener una copia que puedes modificar a tu gusto y ellos opinaron que esto no debe ser así. Con las mismas hicieron la clase String **final** así que tampoco puedes derivar una clase tuya de String y modificar su comportamiento.

Y si te fijas en la clase Object, en la firma del método clone:

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

verás que se pensó para que las clases derivadas de Object sobreescriban su método **clone** a su *imagen y semejanza* y no hay un método genérico que haga el clonado del objeto. Por eso es **protected**. Y por eso no puedes usarlo en String.

Mas o menos es esto. Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

### Sí lo tiene pero está protegido

El código fuente de `Object#clone` muestra:

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

Al ser `String` una clase no extensible y ser `clone` un método `protected` **nadie** tiene acceso a él. En la propia doc se especifica que toda clase que no implemente la interfaz *Cloneable* se lanzará esta excepción:

> - @return     a clone of this instance.
> - @throws  CloneNotSupportedException  if the object's class does not
>                     support the {@code Cloneable} interface. Subclasses
>                    that override the {@code clone} method can also
>                     throw this exception to indicate that an instance cannot
>                     be cloned.

Es decir que se ha de hacer **explicito** que se puede clonar, y `String` no solo no lo especifica, sino que está blindada para que nadie pueda modificarla.

Al final te sería de poca ayuda clonarla porque Java [implementa la Internalización de Strings](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111899/qu%C3%A9-diferencia-hay-en-memoria-de-las-siguientes-2-sentencias/111906#111906).

Answer (score 1):

Es que String ni siquiera lo necesita. Al ser un objeto inmutable, no pueden existir dos String con la misma referencia, por lo que, cuando asignas una variable String a otra, no estas haciendo referencia a el mismo String, si no que lo estas copiando (Creando un nuevo String). Esto hace que el método clone en el caso de los String no sea necesario, ya que al asignar un String a una nueva variable estas haciendo lo mismo que haría el método clone.

Ej:

```
String a = "Hola Mundo";
String b = a;

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);

// Hola Mundo
// Hola Mundo

a = "Azucar";

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);

// Azucar
// Hola Mundo
```

Como puedes ver, no importa si modifico el valor de `a` después de haber asignado su valor a `b`, el valor de `b` sigue siendo el mismo, es decir, el valor de `b` es inmutable.

Answer (score 0):

Una clase String es una variable final, por lo que no se puede clonar. Todos las clases que contiene el método clone() implementan la interfaz Cloneable. Implementar esta interfaz conlleva que la clase no se final.